# Rails model association to hold each month data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations, nested-forms

Could not find a appropriate title to this question sorry for that.

I have a car model. I would like to keep the data of daily and hourly price for each of the month. I could not figure it out how I should construct the model relations.

I tried car has_many dprices (daily price) with columns of month:string price:integer

then 
I tried car has_many hprices (hourly price) with columns of month:string price:integer

Then I tried nested forms. But it does not deliver the data as I want.

```
"car"=>{"prices_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"price"=>"123"}}
```

This looks so complicated. What I want is to get month name and price if possible.

It should look like this;

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making a month model that holds the hourly and daily price. Car has many months, month belongs to car. Then in your view you should be able to call

```
<ul>
  <% @car.months.each do |month| %>
    <li><%= month.name %></li>
    <li><%= month.hprice %></li>
    <li><%= month.dprice %></li>
    <hr>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Sorry for the cruddy write up I'm on my phone haha. But that should at least give you the desired output. Then you can format it however you want.